# Calling an API in jaspersoft

Tags: java, jasper-reports

We have a requirement to create a report which requires multiple queries from around 4 tables. We can use join queries for two of the tables because the key is the same. But the other two has different keys, so it has to be separate keys.

query1 will give us around 7 columns which should be part of the report. Based on one of the field returned from query1, we will have to run query2. Then we have to run query3 based on output of query2.

We pondered various ways to handle this including subqueries, subdatasets in jasper etc but then we encountered another issue. The result of query2 is a json from which we have to extract some data using json and string manipulation which is a bit tricky.

This made us to think about calling a java class which will do all these queries, does json and string manipulations and create entries in a table from which jasper can easily form a report. (Option 1) We need links/guidance on this. Request help here.

Now a subesequent thought came where in jasper is a separate installation for us and our product is bundled in an installer and runs from a different server. So if we put the java class in jasper installation, we will miss out this on subsequent releases because there is no way to track the delivery down the line.
If we incorporate the java functionality in the product by exposing an API and let jasper call that API (API will do the same steps mentioned in Option 1), then it will be easier for us to bundle things. (Option 2)

Since we prefer Option 2, can some one let us know if it is possible to call an API from Jasper before the report generation process. Also the API call has to be synchronous so that it is sure the table loads before report generation. Request everyones valuable feedback here.

Ours is a realtime system and the report generation could be adhoc, so populating the table before hand using a cron may not satisfy the requirement. Please help

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is to create a main report and a sub-report, they will share parameters, so that way you can run the query based on the output of the previous query.

Comment: So basically one report will load the table with contents and the other one will display the report. I am new to this. So does the main report load the table, subreport display or vice versa?

Comment: For example:

Let's say I have an invoice, and the invoice lines. So, you can query the invoice header and do some calculations to print in the main report.

You can use that main query to do the calculations you need to print the lines in the sub-report, since you can have separate datasets from the main report.

Comment: Also is there any onload kind feature to call a java class and then load the jasper report once the table is constructed?

Comment: If there is no intensive calculations, I recommend query database instead of loading java classes.

Comment: There are intensive calculations including json manipulations and querying based on it json content etc